# Get size of a QgsLayoutItemPage in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer

I work on QGIS plugin in python, in my plugin I load several print layout in a project print layout manager. These print  layouts are either A4 or A3. I would like to get the size value (A4 or A3) of each print layout of my project print layout manager. I tried this code but it only returns the size in millimeters of the page.

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
composition = QgsPrintLayout(project)
document = QDomDocument()
template_file = open('C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Composeurs/A4 Portrait.qpt')
template_content = template_file.read()
template_file.close()
document.setContent(template_content)
composition.loadFromTemplate(document, QgsReadWriteContext()) 
project.layoutManager().addLayout(composition)

layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('A4 Portrait')
page_size = layout.pageSize()
print (page_size)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the page type (if exists) with the following code :

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
composition = QgsPrintLayout(project)
document = QDomDocument()
template_file = open("C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Composeurs/A4 Portrait.qpt")
template_content = template_file.read()
template_file.close()
document.setContent(template_content)
composition.loadFromTemplate(document, QgsReadWriteContext()) 
project.layoutManager().addLayout(composition)

layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName("A4 Portrait")
layout_pages = layout.pageCollection()
first_layout_page = layout_pages.page(0)

page_size_registry = QgsApplication.pageSizeRegistry()
page_size = page_size_registry.find(first_layout_page.pageSize())

if first_layout_page.orientation() == QgsLayoutItemPage.Portrait:
    page_size += " Portrait"
if first_layout_page.orientation() == QgsLayoutItemPage.Landscape:
    page_size += " Landscape"

print(page_size)
```

---

**EDIT** : orientation added